# Inserting tokens at end of math mode

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

One can use `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` to insert tokens at the beginning of math mode, but what about inserting tokens at end of math mode? Lets say I want to enclose the math mode material in a pair of DVI specials `begin foo` and `end foo`, how to do that:

```
\everymath{\special{begin foo}}
% where to put \special{end foo}
\everydisplay{\special{begin foo}}
% ditto

Regular text $a+b=c$ more text $$\sqrt{x}=y$$
\bye
```

Comment: does it have to be _inside_ the math or does `\aftergroup\foo `count where `\def\foo{\special{end foo}}`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: it needs to be inside the math.

Comment: That's unfortunate as it's not really possible unless you redefine `$`. (or use luatex I guess) but especially for the inline case there isn't really a lot of meaning to being inside or outside math, it has all been changed to a horizontal box list by that stage in any case.

Comment: My actual use case is enclosing math mode material with `\beginR` and `\endR` commands and here it makes difference as TeX needs to see the `\endR` before finishing the packing of the math mode material, otherwise it will complain about missing `\endR` (I didn’t post that initially as it needs an unreleased version of XeTeX to be even able to use these primitives in math mode).

Comment: Ah well that's a different beast as \beginR needs to work _before_ tex converts the math to an hlist but specials are information to the processor of the dvi output so work after tex has finished.

Comment: As you have the xetex sources to hand could you use a declarative form before the math list to reverse direction rather than relying on beginLR nodes being inserted, perhaps matching luatex's direction control?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That is my contiguous plan, but allowing direction primitives in math mode is simple, so I done that and was hoping to find a way to use it to globally change math direction and avoid engine changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easy to get a special *after* the math:

```
\tracingonline1
\tracingoutput1
\showboxdepth100
\showboxbreadth100

\def\efoo{\special{end foo}}

\everymath{\special{begin foo}\aftergroup\efoo}
% where to put \special{end foo}
\everydisplay{\special{begin foo}\aftergroup\efoo}
% ditto

Regular text $a+b=c$ more text $$\sqrt{x}=y$$
\bye
```

Produces

```
...\mathon
...\special{begin foo}
...\teni a
...\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
...\tenrm +
...\penalty 700
...\glue(\medmuskip) 2.22217 plus 1.11108 minus 2.22217
...\teni b
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\tenrm =
...\penalty 500
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\teni c
...\mathoff
...\special{end foo}
```

and

```
..\hbox(8.49092+1.94444)x32.64345, shifted 218.55577, display
...\special{begin foo}
...\hbox(8.49092+1.90904)x14.04863
....\hbox(0.39998+9.6)x8.33336, shifted -7.69096
.....\tensy p
....\vbox(8.49092+0.0)x5.71527
.....\kern0.39998
.....\rule(0.39998+0.0)x*
.....\kern3.38542
.....\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x5.71527
......\teni x
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\tenrm =
...\glue(\thickmuskip) 2.77771 plus 2.77771
...\teni y
...\kern0.35878
..\penalty 0
..\glue(\belowdisplayshortskip) 7.0 plus 3.0 minus 4.0
..\glue(\baselineskip) 10.05556
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.75499fil
...\special{end foo}
```

To get the specials before the `\mathoff` or inside the display is trickier and probably involves making `$` active which would be incompatible with some uses.

Comment: So this just confirms my understanding that TeX does not provide such a mechanism?

Comment: @KhaledHosny Your understanding is correct.